# Extracting Lines below Specified Words in batch script and change the format

Tags: batch, batch-file

I have a "test.txt" file in the format of:

```
xdfdfdf
ydffddf
zddfdfd
blah ...
WordA
12
23
45
...
32
12
65
xdfdfdf
ydffddf
zddfdfd
blah ...
WordA
54
76
67
...
68
31
85
xdfdfdf
ydffddf
zddfdfd
blah ...
WordA
89
65
45
...
32
51
75
xdfdfdf
ydffddf
zddfdfd
blah ...
....
```

I want to extract only **the numbers** below each "wordA", re-format data **in a row** with a **2 skip format** and make an output file (like "Output.txt"). It must be noted that the No of lines under each "wordA" with numerical data is fixed (for example 18 lines).

The results should be in this format:

```
12 45 ... 32 65
54 67 ... 68 85
89 45 ... 32 75
....
```

Could anybody help me through? I found the FindRepl.bat, however, I cannot employ what I want. I prefer sth simple and brief.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Nice little job:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f %%a in (input.txt) do (
    if "%%~a"=="WordA" (
        if defined line echo(!line:~0,-1!
        set "line="
    )
    (for /f "delims=0123456789" %%b in ("%%~a") do break) || set "line=!line!%%~a "
)
if defined line echo(!line:~0,-1!)>output.txt
```